# hybris FlexibleSearchService can't find a product that actually exists

Tags: search, product, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to add a product to my cart, like this:

```
cartFacade.addToCart("M300044", 2);
```

And it fails with: *Product with code 'M300044' not found!*

When I debug the code, I find that this query is executed by FlexibleSearchService.search(query):

```
SELECT {c:pk} FROM {Product AS c} WHERE {c:code}='M300044'
```

If I execute this query on my hybris Admin console, I do get a Product as a result.

Why can't FlexibleSearchService find it though? Is it something to do with setting a  catalog version somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case it was because I was doing this from a Test class, so hybris couldn´t find the product because there was no data whatsoever in the junit tenant.

So I had to create the data in the setup method of my Test class, which is executed before the actual test method is called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure one more thing that you have set the session user = admin , because if there is a restriction applied on u r product then your test case won't work

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a SYNCHRONIZATION issue.
STAGED Product Version is  not aligned  with Online.
You have two options.
HMC > System > Facet Search > indexer wizard.
Product Cockpit.

Answer (score 0):

Check available stock for product in hmc. May this help you

Comment: The stock level is not a condition in the where clause here.

Answer (score 0):

initialize Junit tenant so by checking import sample data yes so that data which you have in production will be available for testing.

Answer (score -1):

you need to make full SOLR indexing for the products from hmc before they can appear in front end store or using hypris APIs 
hope that help

Comment: The query being executed doesn´t use any SOLR index.